# How to calculate the area of a semi-circle with a triangle over it

Tags: circles

I am trying to find out what the area of this figure is. I make this formula base×height+π×r^2 by myself and I am not sure if it is right. Can anyone correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using Pythagoras theorem, $r=6$ units.
Thus area: $\frac{1}{2}\pi r^2 + \frac{1}{2} b \times h$
where $b$=$2r$ and $h=8$ units

Comment: I think that is write but when used the 0.5×b×h the result was 96. I thought that the must be 100 because  10×10=100(the sides)